# Graphic object outside of C# app - is it doable?

Tags: c#

I have already asked here but the only answer was related to positioning. I would need to make an app which would produce an image always following the mouse, outside of the app. I know now how to hook mouse position, but I have no clue how to let the object (image) be on the top of other apps. Anyway I dont know if it is even possible in .NET.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try `Graphics.FromHdc(IntPtr.Zero)`. In plain old GDI this allowed you to draw directly on the desktop on top of everything. I'm not sure though if this still works in .NET.

**Added:** That said, I'd still go for the trasparent-background-window approach mentioned in another answer. Drawing directly on desktop is waaaay too messy and error-prone.

Answer (score 3):

One of the best and easiest ways to accomplish such a thing is to have a topmost window, with no border and not showing in the taskbar. That would allow you to basically draw whatever you want wherever you want it.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

Form overlay = new Form();
overlay.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
overlay.ShowInTaskbar = false;
overlay.TopMost = true;
```

For bonus points, you could even apply the toolbar-property and revoke it's right to be activated. That will yield a form which does not behave like a window, but like f.e. a tooltip. For that you need to subclass the Form, like this:

```
public class PassiveForm : Form
{
    public PassiveForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams parameter = base.CreateParams;
            parameter.ExStyle |= 0x80; // Apply toolbar-property
            parameter.ExStyle |= 0x8000000; // Revoke acitvation
            return parameter;
        }
    }

    protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Following the mouse around is a little bit harder, but pooling the mouse location should work well enough.

Comment: This is how Google Chrome draws the little arrows when you drag links to the tab bar, they have an always-on-top window with no borders and with a transparent background where it's not an arrow.

Comment: @Bobby: Is this passive Form click-through able?

Comment: @jnovacho: No, not as far as I know. It can still be clicked, but it does not activate in any way by that click.

Comment: @Bobby: I put it wrong. If this form is top most. Is it possible to use underlying windows, desktop and such? Essentially forward Click Events to other components?

Comment: @jnovacho: I never tried it as I always kept this window away from the pointer (I use that as a tooltip replacement which can hold *anything*). To be honest, I don't know the windows event queue good enough to answer if that is possible (well, it is possible for sure, but I don't know how).